# Java client python server socket programming

Tags: java, python, sockets, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a client program in java that sends a message "Hello" to python server.

Java code

```
    import java.io.*;  
    import java.net.*; 
    public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

    try{      
    Socket soc=new Socket("localhost",2004);  
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());  
    dout.writeUTF("Hello");
    dout.flush();
    dout.close();  
    soc.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();}  
    }
```

Python server code

```
    import socket               # Import socket module

    soc = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
    host = "localhost" # Get local machine name
    port = 2004                # Reserve a port for your service.
    soc.bind((host, port))       # Bind to the port
    soc.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
    while True:
    conn, addr = soc.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print ("Got connection from",addr)
    msg = conn.recv(1024)
    print (msg)
    if ( msg == "Hello Server" ):
    print("Hii everyone")
    else:
    print("Go away")
```

the problem is that java client is able to send a Hello message to the python server but in python side else statement always executes with output " Go away".`python version 2.7`

Output:

```
('Got connection from', ('127.0.0.1', 25214))
Hello
Go away
```

Comment: Python does not understand Java's `writeUTF()` format. Only Java's `writeUTF()` understands it. Use `writeBytes()`.

Answer (score 4):

you are getting 'Hello' from client.

```
if ( msg == "Hello" ):
    print("Hii everyone")
else:
    print("Go away")
```

Answer (score 1):

because the string you get on the server side has 2 hidden characters at the beginning, so you must remove these 2 characters before comparing it.

```
if ( msg[2:] == "Hello" ):
```

Comment: it worked for the code `if ( msg[2:] == b"Hello" )` but what are the hidden characters?

Comment: I don't know :D

Answer (score 0):

In the Java code you have written

```
dout.writeUTF("Hello");
```

But the Python server expects "Hello Server" to print "Hii Everyone".

Change Java Client code to

```
dout.writeUTF("Hello Server");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just Use proper syntax. Since you are sending "Hello", "Go away" will be your output.

```
if ( msg == "Hello Server" ):
    print("Hii everyone")
else:
    print("Go away")
```

Comment: This is not a syntax issue,

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have to specify the decryption **UTF-8** in the Python server and then you should use `dout.writeBytes("Hello Server")` in the Java client.

Comment: UTF-8 is not an encryption.